# JQuery: $(this).show() in each(function() { }) doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery from Bear Bibeault et al JQuery in Action.

I'm in the process of learning jquery with the book JQuery in Action by Bear Bibeault et al.I'm trying to create the DVD advanced search page where you click a button "apply filter, and a selection mini form appears to help you search.

basically it clones the div#templates and puts it in a new div under div#selected along with a button to delete it if desired. The selection.filterChooser stays visible and on change is supposed to make the proper div template appear. I can't get this to work

I asked a question about this project earlier but I can't get past this last part:

jsfiddle seems to mess up in ways that it doesn't when I simply test it in chrome. The code throws no erros.

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div#templates').hide();
    $('#addFilterButton').click(function(event) {
        var uniq = Math.random().toString(36).substr(0,10);
        var nnew = $('<div id="div'+uniq+'" class="selected"></div>');
        var button = $('<button type="button" class="filterRemover" title="Remove this filter">X</button>');
        button.click(function(event) {
            $(this).parent('div.selected').remove();
        });
        nnew.append(button);
        var add = $('div#templates').clone().addClass('container'+uniq).show();
        nnew.append(add);
        $('div#selected-filters').append(nnew);
        var f = /filterChooser/;
        $(add).children().each(function(){
            if(f.exec($(this).attr('class'))) { $(this).show(); }
            else { $(this).hide(); }
            $(this).addClass('input'+uniq);
            var tmp = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).attr('name',tmp+uniq);
        });
        $('div[class*='+uniq+'][class*=filterChooser] > select[class=filterChooser]')
        .change(function(event) {
            alert("yes its caught");
            $('div[class*='+uniq+']').children().show();
            $('div[class*='+uniq+']').children().each(function(){
                if(f.exec($(this).attr('class'))) { $(this).show(); }
                else { $(this).hide(); }
            });
            var val = $(this).attr('value');
            alert("val: "+val);
            var proper = "";
            $('div[class*='+uniq+'][class*=filterChooser] > select[class=filterChooser] > option').each(function() {
                var tmp = $(this).attr('value');
                if(val == tmp) { 
                    proper = $(this).attr('data-filter-type');
                    alert("Yes its found: "+proper);
                }
            });
            $('div[class*=template][class*='+uniq+']').each(function() {
                alert($(this).attr('class'));
                var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
                alert("class: "+$(this).attr('class')+", classes[1]: "+classes[1]+", proper: "+proper);
                if(classes[1] == proper) { alert("returning true"); $(this).show(); }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see there are `alert()`s everywhere, and they seem to fire when they're supposed to, so the problem appears to be the last line: `if(classes[1] == proper) { alert("returning true"); $(this).show(); }`

I don't understand why $(this).show() wouldn't work.

html:

```
<fieldset id="field">
<legend>Use this form to do an advanced search for DVDs</legend>
    <div id="selected-filters" class="selected">
    </div>
    <div id="templates">
        <div class="template filterChooser">
            <select name="filter" class="filterChooser" title="Select a property to filter">
                <option value="none" data-filter-type="none" selected="selected">-- choose a filter --</option>
                <option value="title" data-filter-type="stringMatch">DVD Title</option>
                <option value="category" data-filter-type="stringMatch">Category</option>
                <option value="binder" data-filter-type="numberRange">Binder</option>
                <option value="release" data-filter-type="dateRange">Release Date</option>
                <option value="viewed" data-filter-type="boolean">Viewed?</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="template stringMatch">
            <select name="stringMatchType">
                <option value="*">contains</option>
                <option value="^">starts with</option>
                <option value="$">ends with</option>
                <option value="=">is exactly</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="term" />
        </div>

        <div class="template numberRange">
            <input type="text" name="numberRange1" class="numeric" size="3" />
            <span>through</span>
            <input type="text" name="numberRange2" class="numeric" size="3" />
        </div>

        <div class="template dateRange">
            <input type="text" name="dateRange1" class="dateValue" size="11" />
            <span>through</span>
            <input type="text" name="dateRange2" class="dateValue" size="11" />
        </div>

        <div class="template boolean">
            <input type="radio" name="booleanFilter" value="true" checked="checked" />
            <span>yes</span>
            <input type="radio" name="booleanFilter" value="false" />
            <span>no</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pageContent">
        <h1>DVD Ambassador</h1>
        <h2>Disc Locator</h2>

        <form id="filtersForm" action="/fetchFilteredResults" method="post">
            <fieldset id="filtersPane">
            <legend>Filters</legend>
                <div id="filterPane"></div>
                <div class="buttonBar">
                    <button type="button" id="addFilterButton">Add Filter</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="applyFilterButton">Apply Filter</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div id="resultsPane">
                <span class="none">No results displayed</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: looks like `proper` could be any value in your last section since it is defined in prior loop. Use `console.log()` instead of alert for more informative debugging

Comment: Are you famil with phpacademy.org, and thenewboston.com? Great FREE resources for learning jQuery, with better examples, frankly. (Disclosure: I am not associated with either site in any way whatsoever. Just a very happy former user.)

Comment: Not that it matters but I much prefer offline sources as thats where I do most of my work (offline work to do web design lol). But I'll check them out